# Using an Installed Python Module

Tags: python, cmd, module

I have installed python modules using the command from the cmd run.

```
pip install LoRaSim
```

When I ran the command

```
 python test_MarkovChain.py
```

, the error below showed.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_MarkovChain.py", line 2, in <module>
    from LoRaSim.MarkovChain import MarkovChain
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'LoRaSim' .
```

I tried to install the module again in the same path using the same command, but it gave me

```
Requirement already satisfied: LoRaSIm in c:\python\lib\site-packages (0.0.1)
```

How can I use this module knowing that it is NOT installed in the same folder with the file I want to run.

Any help here is truly needed and is well appreciated.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python/on a Mac? If so you have to specify python3/python3.version. Also try doing python3.version -m pip install LoRaSIm

Comment: maybe you have multiple version in python in your system or you running your python file  in venv

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Python 3, try running the command `pip3 install LoRaSim` instead. This error might occur when you have more than one version of Python installed!

Comment: I tried this command, but the same issue.